# Twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy not working while scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am testing out my scrollspy but I do not see it working. When I scroll, the pills do not get highlighted or "Selected". According to http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy, I have all the HTML bits required,

If I am missing anything or you would like more information, feel free to ask!

application.html:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="navbar navbar-default">
<%= yield %>
</body>
```

application.css

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
```

index.html

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <ul id="nav_pills" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Your value for `data-target` is wrong ... you may need `.navbar` instead of just `navbar navbar-default`

Comment: @Danko THIS WORKED! Thanks! I will accept your answer if you post one! Could you explain why only `.navbar` is required? In the example the bootstrap website provided, it seemed like I needed an exact copy of targets class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the value you are using for `data-target` is invalid it needs the `.` if you reference a classname or the `#` if you reference an ID.

In thi case:

> data-target="navbar navbar-default"

Just mention two classnames of the element but you need to identify that it's a classname in order to pass the right selector on the Jquery function. It must be:

> data-target=".navbar.navbar-default"

Without spaces and with the `.` identifier like a normal Jquery selector. You can also simplify this to a single classname:

> data-target=".navbar"

Check this **[BottplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/mTnRjApY7A)** with the right code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm rather new to Bootstrap myself but it appears based on the documentation you still need to call the scrollspy with javascript. Unless you just left that part out of your example.

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.navbar-example' })
```

Comment: I thought this is only one of the methods require. Meaning I can use HTML OR Javascript to do the same task

Comment: This is how the documentation reads to me as well, but it would be worth a shot. I would also try and remove the application.html file and just add it to the body tag in index.html. @Liondancer